# Modifying UV coordinates with Geometry Nodes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I have a mesh input with UV coordinates. I want to add every UV coordinates a float value with Geometry Nodes. I can't find any node that can change UVs. This is a very basic operation in Blender, but don't know, how to do it in GN. Can anyone show a working example of this?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. ...please tell us more about it.

Comment: I am very beginner in GN, just trying to explore the possibilities. I can't get the technique, how can I set UV coordinates for vertices. I found a tutorial that show how to achieve similar effect but this method requires to modify the shader too, because the node tree is not set set the UV coordinates but add an alternative attribute, and the shader use that as mapping coordinates.

This is the tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zXbPRYpi5I

Comment: What part of the 20 minute video are you referring to exactly? There are many solutions here because there are also many starting points. Please edit your question, complete it with a concrete example and try to illustrate your problem with sketches and images or explain precisely at which point you need help. This Q&A platform is not a forum or intended for longer tutorials. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: An example:

I have a mesh input with UV coordinates. I want add every UV coordinates a float value with Geometry Nodes. I can't find any node that can change UVs. This is a very basic operation in Blender, but don't know, how to do it in GN.

Comment: OK, your question is still pretty vague, but I'll try to answer it with a generic example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is a simple example with a cube...

For this cube I have previously created a UV map.

In *Geometry Nodes* I can read this UV-Map with `Named Attribute`. This value is of type *Vector* and describes your UV-Map on the axes *X* and *Y* (*X* corresponds to *U*, and *Y* corresponds to *V*).

By splitting this vector with `Separate XYZ` into its components, you can process them individually with a `Math` node, re-combine them with `Combine XYZ`, and then store them back into the geometry with `Store Named Attribute`.

In the shader you can then process this UV map with the nodes `UV Map` or `Attribute`.

[image]

Note, however, that the attributes are always set to *Face Corner* and not to *Point*, since the coordinates of a UV map always refer to this attribute domain!

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+)*</sub>